# jsf page navigation best practices

Tags: jsf

In JSF page navigation should i use navigation rules defiend in faces-config.xml like

```
 action="#{bean.actionGoToPage}"
 private String actionGoToPage(){
        return "from-outcome";
    }
```

or i can use link to the page direct like

```
href='index.xhtml'
```

what is the best practices?

Comment: `<h:commandLink>` generates a POST HTTP request. Use other components like `<h:link>`, `<h:outputLink>` or `<h:button>`, if it is a pure page-to-page navigation.

Comment: Thanks Tiny My concern not related to which component should i use commandLink or link.My concenr shoud i use navigation rules or call the page direct in the link or cmmand

Comment: You have posted a really bad example, mixing two completely separate concepts. You should instead have asked something like "`<h:commandLink action="from-outcome">` vs `<h:commandLink action="index.xhtml">`". That is also already answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18037884 Regardless, I strongly recommend you to review your JSF learning resources. You should already have known the terms "implicit navigation" and "explicit navigation". This is a good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Mnay thahks its good example