# Can I use wildcard character * in JSF navigation rule?

Tags: jsf, navigation, wildcard

Is there any way in JSF page navigation to create a joker rule? I have a logout link in my template header (almost for all pages). And I want to give just one rule which navigate all the pages inside the secure folder to the index page in the root.

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/secure/*.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>index</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

I tried this, but the parser said it had not found a rule from `/secure/pagex.xhtml` to `/index.xhtml`. Is this true? I have to give a rule for all of my pages one by one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wildcard is only allowed as suffix (as the last character).

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/secure/*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>index</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

The `<from-view-id>` is however optional. You could also just remove it.

```
<navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>index</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Or, better, use implicit navigation, then you can remove the `<navigation-rule>` altogether.

E.g. GET

```
<h:button ... outcome="/index" />
<h:link ... outcome="/index" />
```

Or POST

```
public String logout() {
    // ...

    return "/index?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

JSF will automatically worry about extension and mapping.

#### See also:

- [JSF implicit vs. explicit navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037884/jsf-implicit-vs-explicit-navigation)