# JSF: navigation-rule stopped working after adding parameter to action method

Tags: jsf, navigation, faces-config

I'm modernizing a JSF web application I took over from someone who retired and is not available for questions.

Current job is to simplify a h:dataTable. Each record has a commandLink to go to the corresponding details page.

**Old version:** action method *openDetail()*, determined the selected record by binding of the dataTable and looping trough the records to get the row.

**New version:** action method is now *openDetail(Long id)* and of course I added the parameter to the command link as well.

My action method is called with the correct parameter, I verified this by adding some log output. **But the navigation-rule is not effective anymore.** Although the action method returns the correct outcome, it stays on the page with the table.

The navigation-rule in *faces-config.xml* looks like this:

```
  <navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
      <from-action>#{myBean.openDetail}</from-action>
      <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>/mysks/detail.xhtml</to-view-id>
      <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
  </navigation-rule>
```

Do I need to adapt the navigation-rule ? Does JSF make a difference for overloaded action methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<from-action>` has to **exactly** match the *literal string* as defined in `action` attribute.

So if it currently looks like this:

```xml
<h:commandButton ... action="#{myBean.openDetail(detail.id)}">`
```

Then the `<from-action>` must be exactly that literal string:

```xml
<from-action>#{myBean.openDetail(detail.id)}</from-action>
```

However, the whole navigation rule system has not proven to be really useful in JSF and has become de-facto deprecated since release of JSF 2.0 in 2009 which introduced the new support for immediately returning the `<to-view-id>` as return value, called "implicit navigation". Essentially, XML-based navigation rules are really a "leftover" of the jurassic JSF 1.x and you'd best just get rid of them.

So if you simply adjust the `openDetail()` method from

```java
public String openDetail(Long id) {
    // ...
    return "success";
}
```

to

```java
public String openDetail(Long id) {
    // ...
    return "/mysks/detail.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

then you can get rid of the entire `<navigation-rule>` bloat from the `faces-config.xml`.

#### See also:

- [JSF implicit vs. explicit navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037884/jsf-implicit-vs-explicit-navigation/)

Comment: This web application is over 10 years old, and it was originally implemented in JSF 1.1. I hope I'll get approved some budget for modernizing the navigation as well. On the other hand ... I liked the concept of a centralized navigation configuration as opposed to the "implicit navigation" I just learned about, where the to-view-id's are scattered across the whole web app. Makes it harder to maintain IMO.